# Exception error in Web2Py Admin interface

Tags: python, web2py

I'm in the process of making a website with Web2Py and am having troubles uploading a CSV to populate a database using the appadmin interface.

When try and access the database administration section i get an error which says:

```
File ".../web2py/applications/mysite/controllers/appadmin.py", line 270

except Exception, e:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I went in and edited all the lines with `except Exception, e` to `except Exception as e` in `appadmin.py` and can now access the page but when I try to upload the CSV nothing happens and the data is not uploaded.

i cant show the actual database but it doesnt work when i use the test case of:

```
db.define_table('test',
    Field('Field1','string'),
    Field('Field2','string'))
```

With the CSV:

```
test.Field1,test.Field2
apple, banana
```

I'm using:

> Python 3.6.3
>
> Web2Py 2.16.1

Comment: What version of web2py are you running? Note, if you have upgraded web2py to the latest version (for Python 3 support), you must also upgrade some of the app files, such as appadmin.py, appadmin.html, web2py.js, and web2py_ajax.html. Make sure those are all upgraded and then report back if the problem persists.

Comment: So I have downloaded the source and am running 2.16.1 from there. I replaced the files you mentioned with the copies from the example website with web2py but still no luck.

Comment: Exactly what happens when you attempt an upload? What does the database model look like, and what is the format of the CSV file (maybe show the header and a few rows)?

Comment: I've updated the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV headers should be in `tablename.fieldname` format. For example:

```
test.Field1,test.Field2
apple,banana
```

You can insert a record into the table via appadmin and then export to CSV to see what the file should look like.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help but I've tried altering the csv column headers and the csv still wont upload

Comment: Exactly what happens when you attempt an upload? Any errors?